# Handling free & paid versions of Windows Phone 8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm currently finishing up my very first Windows Phone 8 app. Right now, I'm including ads, and I am planning on selling it for free in the Store. I'm wondering though, what is the best way to go about also including an ad-free, paid version of the app?

Is it better to have two versions in the Store, or have one paid version that has a "trial" version which includes the ads?

For either option, does anyone know of a tutorial or good approach to using the same code base for each version? For example, using the same code for both versions but have the code programmatically determine (based on that version) whether or not to include ads?

**SOLUTION:**

I went with the answer by @DVD below to use an in app purchase system. I found an excelling tutorial for how to do this (which includes testing in the emulator) here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx#IAP_MockLibrary

Comment: What do Microsoft recommend for handling free and paid for versions? Find out and go with that.

Comment: Good call, I plan on looking into that as well, but I was hoping to hear about others' experiences as well.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why? The question is already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows phone 8 I think the best solution is using in-app purchases to remove the ads.

If you use two different versions of the app you are splitting your users, reviews and downloads with 2 apps, remember that reviews and downloads are used to calculate the app rank .

I only recommend this system if you are publishing for the WP7 market as well, because this one doesn't support in app purchases.

Still if you want to use this system, a possible solution is using pre compilation statements.

```
#if PAID_VERSION
(paid version code)
#else
(free version code)
#endif
```

Creating a new Solution Configuration, you can copy Release options and atribute a new name to it, after that you just need to add the symbols on the projects properties in build tab.
After this you select witch solution config you want to deploy and you are done.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply. I won't be publishing for the WP7 market, only WP8. I like the idea of an in-app purchase, I hadn't thought of that. I will probably go this route, so once I'm done I'll come back and mark this as the answer!

Comment: If you also have a trial version be careful not to include calls to LicenseInformation().IsTrial() inside those pre-compilation statements. I did that and after I published the app all trial versions had full access.